# Laravel - Paramaters should be how when we use match route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I want to use match method but I can't take $slug and $request in controller..

Here is my route

```
Route::match(['get','post] , 'category/{slug}' , ['as'=>'category.show' , 'uses'=>'CategoryController@categoryProducts'])
```

in Controller, our function will be how ? How we use that post and get data in the same function ? I tried like below, but dosen't work

```
public function categoryProducts($slug, $request) {
//codes
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use  Request::method();

```
public function categoryProducts(Request $request, $slug) {
      //codes
 }
```

to get request type GET/POST

```
$method = Request::method();
```

or

```
if (Request::isMethod('post'))
{
   // 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to inject `Request` object and not passing it, do this instead:

```
public function categoryProducts(Request $request, $slug)
```